# How to accept urls without a protocol?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

The following is a subclass of Pydantic's BaseModel:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, AnyUrl
class RequestItem(BaseModel):
    links: List[AnyUrl]
```

When I send a request with a body like this:

```
{
    "links": [
        "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "stepik.org"
    ]
}
```

The second url is invalid:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "links",
                1
            ],
            "msg": "**invalid or missing URL scheme**",
            "type": "value_error.url.scheme"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to accept urls without a protocol?

Comment: You need to write your own validator

Comment: FYI: as per the [RFC-3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-1.1.1), each URL must have ***scheme*** (ie, `http`, `https`, `ftp`, etc). In your case, it is not a URL anymore.

Answer (score 4):

As the commenters say, it's not a URL without a scheme.

You'll need your own validators.

The simplest solution should be up add a `pre=True` validators to prepend `http://` if there's no scheme, then let the normal url logic take over.

Example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl, validator


class DemoModel(BaseModel):
    my_url: HttpUrl

    @validator('my_url', pre=True)
    def prepend_http(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, str) and not v.startswith('http'):
            return f'http://{v}'
        return v


print(DemoModel(my_url='google.com').my_url)
print(DemoModel(my_url='https://google.com').my_url)
```

Comment: Could you explain further, what you mean with to add a ``pre=True``. Maybe with an example, please?

Comment: okay, i've done that.